# Possible issue with international characters in objects and/or paths when copying recursively

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've run into a weird problem after uploading a lot of images with gsutil - the uploaded files cannot be seen via the Google Cloud Console and gsutil itself complains if I try to do a 'gsutil ls '. I am 99% sure it is related to the use of "å" or "Å" together with spaces in the directory name.

All uploads were done recursively from a root folder (large image collection in multiple levels of subdirectories). If I try to upload the files again, gsutil skips them since they are already there, so the upload feature does *something* - it just isn't working in the same way as the list and download.

An example:

```
gsutil cp -R -n /Volumes/Photos/digitalfotografen.dk/2009/2009-05-30\ Søgården\ -\ bryllup/ gs://digitalfotografen/2009/
Skipping existing item: gs://digitalfotografen/2009/2009-05-30 Søgården - bryllup/Søgården 0128.CR2
...
```

OK - so the files are there, but browsing the directory through the Google Cloud Console shows "No results".

Also:

```
gsutil ls gs://digitalfotografen/2009/2009-06-27 Søgården - reklamefotos/20090627_IMG_0128.CR2
CommandException: "ls" command does not support "file://" URIs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URI?
```

I tried escaping spaces and used quotation marks in different ways with no luck.

Now, here is the interesting thing:

```
gsutil cp -R -n /Volumes/Photos/digitalfotografen.dk/2009/2009-05-30\ Søgården\ -\ bryllup/ gs://digitalfotografen/2009/
Copying file:///Volumes/Photos/digitalfotografen.dk/2009/2009-05-30 Søgården - bryllup/Søgården 0128.CR2 [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
```

Here I copied the folder specifically with escaped spaces on the *source* side, and now the files are uploaded again. This creates a second folder with the same name (at least it appears so in the Cloud Console) and the files are now visible in *both* folders.

We use three different characters that are outside the standard US ASCII in the Danish character set ("æøå" and the capital "ÆØÅ") but the problem *only* seems to affect "å" and "Å" - the two others alone or in combination works fine. My hunch is that "å" and "Å" may translate into something entirely different in ASCII that throws things off track when gsutil is allowed to handle the directory naming on its own based on the name of the root folder (doing a multiple level recursion) but works when the user specifies the escaped name of the root folder.

This may be a python issue rather than a gsutil issue, but I am in no way qualified to identify this since I have very close to zero knowledge of programming outside a bit of hodgepodge shell scripts.

Comment: This does look to be a bug. We're investigating. I'll post back here when we have an update.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

A bit of additional info: The folders created with the recursive copy cannot be removed again via the Cloud Console, but it can be done via gsutil *if* the folders are given as wildcards *before* the 'å'. An example:

`localhost:~ anders$ gsutil rm -R gs://digitalfotografen/2009/'2009-06-06 Søgå'*
CommandException: No URIs matched: gs://digitalfotografen/2009/2009-06-06 Søgå*`

Remove the final 'å' before the wildcard:

`localhost:~ anders$ gsutil rm -R gs://digitalfotografen/2009/'2009-06-06 Søg'*
Removing gs://digitalfotografen/2009/2009-06-06 Søgården - grillaften/...`

Comment: this should be fixed now if you wouldn't mind confirming it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

We got a trouble with gsutil into ubuntu wsl version windows 10. 
The command gsutil work perfectly into the shell but not working when is included into a shell script:

`gsutil -m  ls -lr gs://project.appspot.com/`

Error:

```
commandexception: "ls" command does not support "file://" urls. did you mean to use a gs:// url?
```

A workaround cloud be by calling directly the script /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil and not calling the link /usr/bin/gsutil:

`/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil -m  ls -lr gs://project.appspot.com/`

I don't know why but it's working.

Thank Marion to provide us a such uncommon bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this here is a old error, but nevertheless I had a similar issue as described above.

```
CommandException: "ls" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?
```

Using `gsutil` from scala code.

```
import sys.process._


object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val clients = s"gsutil ls gs://<bucket name>".!!
    val beforeDate: String = "date +%Y-%m-%d -d '-8 days'".!!
    val clientList = clients.split("\n").map(f => f.split('/').apply(1)).toList
    for (x <- clientList) {
      val countImg = (s"gsutil -m ls gs://<bucket name>/$x/${beforeDate.stripLineEnd}" #| "wc -l").!!
      println(countImg)
    }
  }
}
```

So what I found was that there was a `LineEnd` character on the `beforeDate`, when I striped that the error went away. So the error occurs when there is a "special" character in the `gs://...` path. So be sure to strip variables for any "special" characters.
And all this happened just because I was to lazy to use `java.time.LocalDate` to generate the `beforeDate` variable. Hope this here will help others that encounter the same error.